# Prevent "Open Project" Dialog from showing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

In last versions of Visual Studio IDE, if I open it without specifying a ".sln" or ".vbproj" file as parameter, it immediately opens a "Open Project" dialog. But most of times I do this, that's because I want to start a new project. **Can I prevent "Open Project" dialog from showing on VS IDE Startup?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to change your Visual Studio Startup options. Click `Tools`->`Options`. Under `Environment`, select `Startup`.  Change the `At Startup` option:

[image: VS Startup Options]